# Use cookies server-side from different domain in NextJS 13

Tags: next.js, cookies, server-side, same-origin-policy, payload-cms

I'm building a full-stack application which has a backend (PayloadCMS) and a frontend (in NextJS 13) hosted on different domains (e.g. backend: `1.1.1.1`, frontend: `2.2.2.2`)

I'm using cookies to handle authentication, and when a user login in frontend (`2.2.2.2`), my backend sets a cookie (with domain origin `1.1.1.1`), I setup the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in NextJS properly to accept cookies from backend, so the cookie is set, with `1.1.1.1` as `Domain`

When I try to retrieve my cookie from server-side component using

```js
import { cookies } from "next/headers";

const cookieStore = cookies();
```

the cookie is not retrieved, I imagine because the Domain of the cookie is not the same as the NextJS server.

I also tried to put the `Domain` of the cookie the same as the frontend (`1.1.1.1`), but my browser blocks it and doesn't set it, I also tried to put as `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` the frontend domain, but still browser doesn't set the cookie.

What I was thinking as a solution is to use a common domain for both frontend and backend, but I can't believe this is the only solution to this problem. I was also planning on setting another cookie when I receive the cookie from backend, putting as domain the frontend domain, but I don't think this is the best solution.

Is there a way to solve this issue without using the same domain? I'm not so proficient with cookies and CSRF, so also some guides or documentation on it would be welcome!